# MetaTag Description - Caracteres especiais - Influência no SEO

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, seo

Minha `metatag description` é composta por um texto, **o qual possuí acentos**. 
Eu crio ela no meu `Controller` MVC e envio para a `view` via `viewbag`.

Porém, no meu texto html (via *exibir código fonte da página*) está ficando com a codificação diferente, ou seja, os acentos viram aqueles códigos. Por exemplo:
**Texto original**: Evento do Produtor's Event em 10 Kirkpatrick St, até N...
**Texto Gerado**: Produtor's Event em 10 Kirkpatrick St, at&#233...

> **Pergunta**: Devo me preocupar com isso? Devo corrigir isso? 
>   Se sim, como?
>   Os robôs interpretariam a informação independente da codificação usada?

Answer (score 0):

A solução é simples. 
Basta adicionar o helper `@Html.Raw`

Vide exemplo:
`<meta name="description" content="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.description)" />`